# Vector as directional derivate?

Tags: tensors

> The Poor Man’s Introduction to Tensors - by Justin C. Feng.
>   https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~jcfeng/notes/Tensors_Poor_Man.pdf

On page 3, "Before I can tell you what a tensor is, I must tell you what a vector really is; in fact, you will later see that a vector is a type of tensor.
A vector is simply a directional derivative. Before you write me off as a nut, take a look at the directional derivative of some scalar function $f(x^i)$"

$$\nu.\nabla(f(x^j))=\nu^i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}f(x^j)$$

To me this is still ok, the author later removes the function itself and claim,

$$\nu.\nabla=\nu^i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}$$
currently i see $\nu.\nabla$ as some form of operator.

But my trouble arises when on page 4, equation 19, author then gives equation, stating the following "Some people get rid of the function f altogether, and write the following:"

$$\nu=\nu^i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{x^i}}$$
and $$\nu^i = \nu(x^i)$$

My problem is that seem that this definition of vector seems very un-intuitive to me,maybe because i am acquainted with all the old definition. It is as if vector were a operator. Can anyone give me the intuition behind this? Or can someone help me make its sense in term of old definitions of vector i have like in simple Euclidean geometry.

Edit: Just to be exact from the possible duplicate, My problem with intuition is exactly this new operator kind of definition **As compared to** n-tuple that i have been seeing all along. Exactly how do they connect if they do so, Or if they are different or if one generalizes the other.

Comment: Regarding your edit: You have probably learned that a vector is an $n$-tuple that transforms in a certain way during change of coordinates. If you take a look at $\partial/\partial x^\mu$, this transforms as $\partial/\partial y^\mu=\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial y^\mu}\partial/\partial x^\nu$. From this you can derive the components of "differential operator vectors" transform the same way as your $n$-tuples do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In euclidean geometry you have a so called affine structure, which essentially states that points are separated by translation vectors. An affine space is a set of points $A$ together with a vector space $V$ and an action of $V$ on $A$ as an abelian group: If $p\in A$ is a point and $v\in V$ is a vector then $p+v\in A$ is another point of $A$, and we can view $v$ as a vector that points from $p$ to $p+v$.

The reason we don't use affine spaces most of the time, is that if you fix a designated point, which we shall call the origin, $O$, then $A$ and $V$ canbe identified. The point $p$ in $A$ is identified with the vector $v\in V$ for which $p=O+v$. The nature of the abelian group action is defined in such a way to make this identification unique.

Why am I saying all this? Because if we want to define a vector **at** a point, rather than one that points between points (remember, in physics, the electric field at $x$, $E(x)$ is a vector that is located at $x$ but it doesn't point to any other point, it just has a magnitude and direction), the affine structure will enable that:

If you want to have a vector at $p$, you can take a straight curve $\gamma(t)=p+tv$ $(p\in A,\ v\in V)$, and take the derivative $$ \left.\frac{d}{dt}(p+tv)\right|_{t=0}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{(p+hv)-p}{h}=v, $$ however by taking a look at the last limit, you can see the vector points from $p$ to $p+hv$ where $h$ tends to zero. The vector is **at** $p$.

**Tensor calculus on the other hand**, even if implicit, takes place generally on a differentiable manifold, a generalization of curves and surfaces to higher dimensions. A differentiable manifold is usually **not** an affine space, so we **cannot** define vectors the same way I did above. We **have** to use some other way to grasp the intuitive concept of a direction and magnitude at a point, without relying on this affine structure.

There are multiple ways to do this, one is to take an equivalence class of curves at a point, two curves being equivalent if they go through the point both and also their derivatives in any chart also coincide. This grasps the point of a "velocity" at a point. Another way to do it is to take first-order differential operators that act on scalar functions. This characterizes the concept of a vector by being the "velocity" with which you differentiate functions in a certain direction.

In the end, it doesn't actually matter. A recurring point in modern mathematics is that it doesn't so much matter **what** an object is, aside from what it can do and what its properties are. It however **is** useful to take vectors to be differential operators whatever definition you use, if for nothing else because it can reduce notational clutter. You can write $X(f)$ for the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of $X$ instead of $d_Xf$, and you can write the commutator of two vector fields $X$ and $Y$ as $$ [X,Y](f)=XY(f)-YX(f) $$ instead of $$ [X,Y]=d^{-1}[d_X,d_Y] $$ for example.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure most people as they are learning mathematics think of a vector as an arrow in space. This is useful but it isn't strictly correct.

What is a vector then? A vector is an element of a vector space.

So the answer to your question is actually fairly simple. An operator can be a vector by being an element of a vector space.

I would recommend that you prove that the appropriate set of directional derivative operators can be turned into a vector space.

It would also be worthwhile for your understanding to see if you can associate each operator with a vector in $\Bbb R^n$ and then make that connection rigorous by constructing an isomorphism between the two vector spaces.

Comment: This explains why one can call the set of certain differential operators on scalar functions a "vector space" (and, consequently, how its elements can be called "vectors" in an abstract sense) -- but not how it is useful to use those operators _in place of_ the geometric vectors we already know and love (and which _also_ form an abstract vector space). Note that the OP is quoting from physics notes, and physicists use "vectors" with a narrower meaning than mathematicians do.

Comment: I'm not sure that the OP is asking why it is useful to use those operators? Although I am certain that will be a question he will ask!

Comment: x @Bernard: Well, the point is not just that they form a vector space, or that it is a vector space that's useful in itself, but specifically that these operators correspond uniquely to geometric vectors, and that tensor calculus prefers to use them _to represent ordinary geometric vectors_ instead of geometric vectors themselves.

Comment: Exactly the point! thanks! "tensor calculus prefers to use them to represent ordinary geometric vectors instead of geometric vectors themselves"

Comment: @HenningMakholm I see your point. I think I had the same thing in mind when I suggested that the OP should try to construct the isomorphism between the two spaces and I just took for granted that once that is done the 'connection' the OP was asking for should be obvious.